# Select from drop list but add different value to cell in Excel

Tags: excel

Is there anyway to select from a drop down list in Excel but instead of the selected value in list being added into the cell a different value is added.
e.g. Drop down list in A1 contains A, B, C, D, E.
If I select A from list, 1 is added to cell A1, If I select B from list, 2 is added to cell A1... and so on.
Can this be achieved with a formula in Data Validation List or VBA.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use a regular data validation, and then have a conditional format that checks the cell's value (your example would need 5 different conditional formats, one for each possible value), and then set the conditional format to be a custom format.  For example, to show a 1, the custom format would be `;;;"1"`

Comment: That will work just fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular data validation, and then have a conditional format that checks the cell's value (your example would need 5 different conditional formats, one for each possible value), and then set the conditional format to be a custom format. For example, to show a 1, the custom format would be `;;;"1"`